# Multitenant website in azure

Tags: azure

I have a content management system(CMS) which is used for 10 websites, currently they are with different hosting providers so for each websites we have deployed same application with different database connection.
Now I want to create a single web application in azure and redirect all the 10 websites to the azure with some unique Identifier so that azure web application identifies which website had send the request and respond him accordingly, also the url of the website should display different url instead of common url for all website.

**My question is 
1) Is it possible if yes how?**

Answer (score 2):

One option is to point different DNS hostnames to the same web app in Azure, e.g. cust1.mycms.com, cust2.mycms.com.

In the web application, you need to inspect the host header to discern between the tenants so that you choose a different connection depending on the header value.

If you do not need to add new tenants frequently, this is an approach that is easy to implement. Be careful however to not allow a tenant to access another tenant's data.

You might want to have a look at [this eBook](https://www.syncfusion.com/resources/techportal/details/ebooks/aspnetmultitenant). It describes several options regarding multi-tenancy in ASP.NET applications.